# Select case for various input amounts

Tags: arrays, vb.net, function, for-loop, select-case

This is what I have so far;

```
    Function myChoice(ByVal opt1 As String, ByVal opt2 As String, ByVal opt3 As String, ByVal opt4 As String)

    Dim choose As String
    Dim mynum As Integer

    Randomize()
    mynum = Int(Rnd() * 4 + 1)

    Select Case mynum
        Case 1
            choose = opt1
        Case 2
            choose = opt2
        Case 3
            choose = opt3
        Case 4
            choose = opt4
    End Select

    myChoice = choose

End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    MsgBox(myChoice("Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green"))

End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is not have the ByVal opt1 as string, ByVal op2 .....
If I have say 100 colours, how do I make the function have 100 opt's and there for 100 'case' events without typing it all in?

I thing I may need a loop and maybe an array but other than that, I am stumped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make use of the [`ParamArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct363x9h.aspx) parameter. Then use the [`Random`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.random%2528v%3Dvs.110%2529.aspx&ei=hMpXVZuaLozvtQXk0YCgBg&usg=AFQjCNGSBmllDVxqPe0wWaFJaXc5lMWZ8Q&sig2=iH5WphRMB2oBCvY7L9XlrQ) class to get a random item. I would use the top one if you are going to call this method several times in a short time.

```
Function ChooseOne(ParamArray opts() As String)
  Static rnd As New Random
  Return opts(rnd.Next(0, opts.Count))
End Function
```

Or simpler yet!

```
Function ChooseOne(ParamArray opts() As String)
  Return opts(New Random().Next(0, opts.Count))
End Function
```

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that your simpler method is not suitable for cases where `ChooseOne` may be called several times in a very short period of time (typically 15 milliseconds) as it is likely to return the same value serveral times. In general, I prefer your first method.

Comment: Yeah, I almost commented on that for the seed aspect. Thanks for your attention to this. @Blackwood